# How to convert range of values to 1 and 0 for use in sumproduct

Tags: excel

```
Values      Dates
0       31/12/2020
0       31/12/2021
7       31/12/2022
0       31/12/2023
0       31/12/2024
```

I have two ranges of data similar to the table above and I would like to use the built-in Sumproduct formula in such a way to return the date of the non-zero value (in this case 31/12/2022). Do anyone know how I can go about this?

I would prefer if this was possible without first creating a third row/column which calculates ones and zeros from the Values range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<>` within `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6*(A2:A6<>0))
```

[image]

This will return unexpected results if you have more than one nonzero value in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that the formula `=NOT(NOT(A2)) * 1` turns a non-zero value into 1?

Like this, you can do something like (using a helper column with the mentioned formula):

```
Values|      Dates|Values_1_0
------+-----------+----------
     0| 31/12/2020|         0
     0| 31/12/2021|         0
     7| 31/12/2022|         1
     0| 31/12/2023|         0
     0| 31/12/2024|         0
```

Sumproduct formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C6,B2:B6)`
=> result : 31/12/2022

Comment: Didn't OP ask though to not create a helper column?

Comment: @BigBen: I tried using the `NOT(NOT())` trick in my `SumProduct()` formula, but I failed, hence the helper column. If you know a way to do this, don't hesitate improving my answer.

Comment: @BigBen: I was writing mine when you posted yours, I didn't have the time to react (sometimes things go fast here :-) ).